# Dropwizard user registration (basic, social, OpenID, OAuth, Google+)

Tags: authentication, oauth, dropwizard

I am writing my first Dropwizard based application. It's a proof-of-concept for a somewhat skeptical boss at a well established php shop.

One thing I'm trying to do is to create what is simple using our existing framework:

1. Allow users to create an account using their email+password, send a verification email and mark their account as active, then allowing them to log in using basic passwd authentication.
2. Allow the same using google (which now I see is changing to google+)
3. Allow the same using Facebook, but then also allow them to change the email address Facebook gives me.

I've found the openId integration example, and various other articles referring to versions that always seem out of date (or just don't seem to work) and three days in I'm getting ready to give up. I'm sure someone must have done this before and made it public. Please tell me so.

Comment: When you reference the OpenID example, [do you mean this one](https://github.com/gary-rowe/DropwizardOpenID)? If it's not working for you, please raise an issue against it.

Comment: To be clear, your OpenID example works beautifully, but does not support OAuth2, which google is pushing and which of course offers secondary advantages wrt accessing proprietary data on FB, Google, etc., over plain old authentication.

Comment: Dropwizard supports Basic and OAuth by default [official git here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-auth) . Or you can write your custom authenticator specific to your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Ken Yee has an example:

https://github.com/kenyee/dropwizard-oauth-openid

which is based off Gary Rowe's example but added Oauth support using [SocialAuth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/). It may be a good start.